# Yii and XSS, where to escape the data?

Tags: yii, xss

Where to escape the user input in Yii?

1. Should I call `CHtml::encode(strip_tags())` before saving them in to db?
   Or I should encode them rather right in the view, before `echo`?
2. Is there a way to automatically encode input text in validation?
   Does validation by [a-zA-Z0-9]* is the best way to filter injections in validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one this is my personal opinion but I would do as you said: `CHtml::encode(strip_tags())` before saving the data. The main advantage of doing it before is that if you are getting the datas from different medium (a website, an api, ...) you'll be sure that the retrieved data are safe.

For the second point I don't know if there is a specific method to automatically encode the input text, but you could use one of the `beforeValidate()` and `beforeSave()` methods in your model to do it!

For security in yii I invite you to check the wiki about [writing secure yii applications](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications)

Comment: The problem is that `CHtml::input($model, 'name', ...)` uses `CHtml::encode` by default, so already encoded text from db will be encoded again. For example, `&quot;` from db will be displayed as `&amp;quot;` in the input field.However, one could modify CHtml class, but it is definitely not the best practice

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
  $p = new CHtmlPurifier();
  $p->options = array(
    'URI.AllowedSchemes' => array(
      'http' => true,
      'https' => true,
  ));
  $search = CHtml::encode($p->purify($search));
```

Put that inside a function and call it whenever :)